# php is_numeric and strlen return true even when false

Tags: php, strlen

I am using a submit form to submit an 8 digit number. I am trying to use is_numeric and strlen to make sure that "12345678" returns successful however "adsf" and "123" also return successful. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing to make this happen.

```
<?php 

  if (!empty($_POST['WorkOrder']) && isset($_POST['WorkOrder'])) {

      if (!is_numeric($_POST['WorkOrder']) && (!strlen($_POST['WorkOrder']) == 8)) {

?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            You cannot enter a blank or invalid work order number! You entered <?php echo "\"".$_POST['WorkOrder']."\""; ?>
                        </div>

<?php
  } else {
  $sql1 = "";
?>

                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <?php echo $_POST['WorkOrder']. " has been updated successfully!"; ?>
                        </div>

<?php

    //mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
  } } ?>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `empty()` also checks if the variable `isset()`. No need to use the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use OR not AND and compare strlen to 8 value

```
if (!is_numeric($_POST['WorkOrder']) || strlen($_POST['WorkOrder']) !== 8) {
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `!` before your functions which can also be translated to `is not`.

What you are actually asking is: `Is this variable not numeric?` and `Is this variable not of lenghth ...`.

Instead you should use `if (is_numeric($var) && strlen($var) == ...)`

Good luck!